# Why is Javascript not working in webview in my UWP application?

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

So I've created a UWP application in Visual Studio that uses a webview to load a local html file. The html file uses Javascript to validate the user's input and will display a message box if the user enters incorrect data into any of the fields after clicking a button. The file works just fine when I run it in a web browser, but when it's run through the webview, the Javascript ceases to function (Where no message box is displayed for any incorrect data entered).

This is the code that creates the URI and navigates to the HTML content:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Register_js.html");
webView1.Navigate(myUri);
```

I'm not sure why Javascript doesn't work when I load a local file but works perfectly fine when I load google.com (which would obviously use Javascript).

Does anyone know how I can get Javascript to work for a local file?

Edit: here is the code of the HTML file I'm trying to load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Registration Form</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

  function ValidateForm()
  {
    var regExp=/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;
    if (document.newUserForm.firstname.value=="")
    { alert("Firstname field cannot be blank.");
      document.newUserForm.firstname.focus();
      return false;}
      if (document.newUserForm.surname.value=='')
    {
      alert('Surname field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.surname.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (!regExp.test(document.newUserForm.DOB.value) )
    {
    alert('The Field is not correctly formatted!');
    document.newUserForm.DOB.focus();
    return false;
    };
      if (document.newUserForm.homePhone.value=='')
    {
      alert('Home Phone field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.homePhone.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(document.newUserForm.homePhone.value))
    {
      alert('Home Phone field must be a number.');
      document.newUserForm.homePhone.focus();
      return false;
    }

      if (document.newUserForm.roomNo.value=='')
    {
      alert('Room No. field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.roomNo.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.workPhone.value=='')
    {
      alert('Work Phone field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.workPhone.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.fax.value=='')
    {
      alert('Fax field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.fax.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.emailAddress.value=='')
    {
      alert('Email Address field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.emailAddress.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.password.value=='')
    {
      alert('Password field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.password.value.length<5)
    {
      alert('Password field must be at least five characters.');
      document.newUserForm.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.confirmPassword.value=='')
    {
      alert('Confirm Password field cannot be blank.');
      document.newUserForm.confirmPassword.focus();
      return false;
    }
      if (document.newUserForm.password.value!=document.newUserForm.confirmPassword.value)
    {
      alert('Password fields do not match.');
      document.newUserForm.confirmPassword.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if (document.newUserForm.gender.value=="male")
    {
    alert('Gender is male.');
    return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2><strong>New User Details</strong></h2>
    <form name="newUserForm" method="post" action="registerUserDisplay.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();">
        <table style="width: 500px; border: 0px;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="firstname" type="text" style="width: 200px;" maxlength="100" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Surname</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="surname" type="text" style="width: 200px;" maxlength="100" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="gender" id="gM" type="radio" value="M" /><label for="gM">Male</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input name="gender" id="gF" type="radio" value="F" checked="checked" /><label for="gF">Female</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td><input name="bender" id="gB" type="radio" value="B" /><label for="gB">Bender</label></td>
                <td>D.O.B.<small> (YYYY-MM-DD)</small></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="DOB" type="text" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="10" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Home Address</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="homeAddress" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Home Phone</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="homePhone" type="text" style="width: 150px;" maxlength="15" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Work Details</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Position</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="positionID">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Permanent</option>
                        <option value="2">Full-Time</option>
                        <option value="3">Part-Time</option>
                        <option value="4">Casual</option>
                        <option value="5">Volunteer</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Room No.</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="roomNo" type="text" style="width: 50px;" maxlength="5" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Work Phone</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="workPhone" type="text" style="width: 150px;" maxlength="15" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Fax</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="fax" type="text" style="width: 150px;" maxlength="15" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Mobile</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="mobilePhone" type="text" style="width: 150px;" maxlength="15" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="emailAddress" type="text" style="width: 200px;" maxlength="200" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Department</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="deptID">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Accounts</option>
                        <option value="2">Human Resources</option>
                        <option value="3">Help Desk</option>
                        <option value="4">Management Information Systems</option>
                        <option value="5">Public Relations</option>
                        <option value="6">Communications</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="password" type="password" style="width: 200px;" maxlength="20" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>Confirm Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="confirmPassword" type="password" style="width: 200px;" maxlength="20" />*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div align="right">* indicates required field</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us your code?

Comment: Ok I just added the code for the HTML file

Comment: @selbie Any luck with this problem?